# Simplifying trig expression

Tags: trigonometry

I have

$$\frac{\tan{15^\circ}}{1-\tan{15^\circ}^2}$$

and need to simplify it. The only equation I have that is even close to a match for it is $2\frac{\tan{15^\circ}}{1-\tan{15^\circ}^2}$. But the numerator isn't right with the $\times 2$. The answer should be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$. What do I do with this?

Comment: It looks like a match to me, since you can always rewrite a given expression into (1/2) (2*expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
2 \frac{\tan(15^{\circ})}{1-\tan(15 ^{\circ})^2} = \tan(30) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \tag{1}
$$

because:

$$
 \frac{\tan(\alpha) + \tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)} = \tan(\alpha+\beta) \tag{2}
$$

Following equation (1):

$$
\frac{\tan(15^{\circ})}{1-\tan(15 ^{\circ})^2} = \frac{1}{2}\tan(30) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}
$$

And finally we employ a very useful method in dealing with roots, multiplying by $1$:

$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$$

Comment: The book says the answer should be $sqrt(3)/6$ though. I still ca't figure out how you get to that.

Comment: @windy401 $\sqrt3/6=1/(2\sqrt3)$

Comment: Ohhhh. Ok, I see it now. You can multiply both halves by $\sqrt(3)$. Didn't realize you could do that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

One has the identity $\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$. Hence $\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}=\frac{\tan(2x)}{2}$. This is what Rolf says.